# CMake add list of subdirectories

Tags: c++, cmake

In my CMake project I need to add a list of subdirectories.

1. The correct way is not nice because I can not pass a list:

   ```
   add_subdirectory(Helpers)
   add_subdirectory(Lib1)
   add_subdirectory(Lib2)
   ```
2. `subdirs` can pass a list, but is deprecated:

   ```
   subdirs(Helpers
           Lib1
           Lib2)
   ```

**Is there a way to add subdirectories as a list?** It seems like a common usecase.

If not: **Why was it discontinued?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `foreach()`:

```
foreach(SUBDIR IN ITEMS
    Helpers
    Lib1
    Lib2
)
    add_subdirectory(${SUBDIR})
endforeach()
```

You could even wrap this in a custom function

```
function(my_subdirs SUB1)
    foreach(SUBDIR IN ITEMS ${SUB1} ${ARGN})
        add_subdirectory(${SUBDIR})
    endforeach()
endfunction()

...

my_subdirs(
    Helpers
    Lib1
    Lib2
)
```

Comment: The first option is a nice workaround! Any idea why they don't allow lists anymore?

Comment: @Chris `subdirs` still seems to be listed as deprecated command for the upcoming version 3.24, so you should still be able to usse the command, but probably it was an effort to encourage the use of a single command for the purpose of adding subdirectories encouraging the use of the more powerful one that's more in line with the usual command naming convetion of noun+verb for these kinds of functionality...

Comment: Fair enough. I'll still wait a bit for other suggestions before closing.